# Center of endomorphisms of finitely generated projective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and $S$ be a finitely generated projective $R$-module. Consider $\text{End}_R(S)$, the set of $R$-module endomorphisms of $S$. This is naturally an $R$-algebra, where the product is given by composition. My question is: is the center of $\text{End}_R(S)$ equal to $R$, where we see every element $r$ of $R$ as the endomorphism that maps $s\in S$ to $rs$?

My attempt: this is clearly true if $S$ is free of rank $n$, since $\text{End}_R(S)$ can be seen as the ring of matrices $n\times n$ with coefficients in $R$, and the center consists precisely of the scalar matrices. I tried to generalise this approach: since $S$ is finitely generated and projective, we may find a projective coordinate system: a set $\{s_i,f_i\}_{i=1}^n$, with $s_i\in S$, $f_i\in \text{Hom}_R(S,R)$ such that, for every $s\in S$, $$s=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(s)s_i.$$ If $\gamma\in \text{End}_R(S)$, then we can associate to $\gamma$ a matrix: for every $j=1,\ldots, n$, write in columns the coefficients of $\gamma(s_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(\gamma(s_j))s_i$. We find a ring homomorphism from $\text{End}_R(S)$ to $\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(R)$. The problem here is that this homomorphism is not surjective, so we cannot conclude that the center of $\text{End}_R(S)$ corresponds to the scalar matrices...

Comment: In the case when $S$ is free, why is the endomorphisms all matrices? It is true if you are considering endomorphisms of $S$ as an $R$ module, not algebra endomorphisms.

Comment: Of course, that was a mistake in the question. Sorry, and thank you for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that the question is local, so you can reduce to the local case where $S$ is free.

You have exhibited a homomorphism $R\to Z(\operatorname{End}_R(S))$ and you are asking whether this homomorphism is surjective. Now a homomorphism of $R$-modules is surjective iff its localization at each prime ideal of $R$ is surjective.  I claim that if you localize $Z(\operatorname{End}_R(S))$ at a prime $p\subset R$, you just get $Z(\operatorname{End}_{R_p}(S_p))$.  First, if you localize $\operatorname{End}_R(S)$ at $p$, you get $\operatorname{End}_{R_p}(S_p)$ since $S$ is a finitely presented $R$-module.  This makes $Z(\operatorname{End}_R(S))_p$ naturally a central subring of $\operatorname{End}_{R_p}(S_p)$.  To see that this subring is actually the whole center, suppose an element $f\in\operatorname{End}_{R_p}(S_p)$ is central; we wish to show that $f$ is just a central element of $\operatorname{End}_R(S)$ divided by some element of $R\setminus p$.  Multiplying $f$ by an element of $R\setminus p$, we may assume we can lift $f$ to an element $\bar{f}\in\operatorname{End}_R(S)$.   Fix a finite set of generators $g_1,\dots,g_n$ for $\operatorname{End}_R(S)$ as an $R$-module.  Since $f$ is central, $\bar{f}$ commutes with each $g_i$ after multiplying by some element of $R\setminus p$.  Since we have only finitely many $g_i$, we can multiply $\bar{f}$ by a single element of $R\setminus p$ to assume that it commutes with every $g_i$.  That means $\bar{f}\in Z(\operatorname{End}_R(S))$, as desired.

So, localizing $Z(\operatorname{End}_R(S))$ at a prime $p$ just gives $Z(\operatorname{End}_{R_p}(S_p))$.  But $S_p$ is free over $R_p$, so the canonical homomorphism $R_p\to Z(\operatorname{End}_{R_p}(S_p))$ is surjective.  It follows that your homomorphism $R\to Z(\operatorname{End}_R(S))$ is surjective.

(Note that this does not mean that $Z(\operatorname{End}_R(S))$ "is" $R$, since the homomorphism may not be injective.  For instance, consider what happens if $S=0$.  In general, you can say that every central endomorphism of $S$ is given by multiplication by an element of $R$, but that element of $R$ may not be unique.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a couple of follow-up questions. 1) So here the projectivity is necessary to define the homomorphism. Can we add hypothesis in order to find that the homomorphism is also injective? 2) Does this work also if we consider, for example, completions instead of localisations? 3) Do you know if there is a reference for this result, or something similar, on some books?

Comment: Sorry, I think that projectivity is not necessary to define the map, but to find, when we localise, that the module is free.

Comment: Projectivity is used primarily to know that after localizing, $S_p$ is free over $R_p$.  It is also subtly used in some of the finiteness conditions--for instance, to know that $\operatorname{End}_R(S)_p=\operatorname{End}_{R_p}(S_p)$, you need to know that $S$ is finitely *presesnted* and not just finitely generated, which is automatic for projective modules but not in general.  Similarly, to know the center respects localization, you need to know that $\operatorname{End}_R(S)$ is finitely generated, which is because it is a summand of $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R^n,S)$.

Comment: These uses of projectivity for finiteness conditions are unnecessary if you assume $R$ is Noetherian (then finite generation of $S$ automatically implies all the finiteness you need).

Comment: I think as long as $R$ is Noetherian you should be able to use completions instead of localizations everywhere.  I'm not sure why you'd want to, though; that just makes the arguments more complicated.  I don't know a reference off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!